# How to achieve three stage list items that have checkboxes?

Tags: android, checkbox

I am new to android development and i want to achive similar that is in wifi or bluetooth activity has..

1. on clicking the 'Turn on bluetooth' the list item displayed as temporerly disabled effect (gray)
2. simultaneously the below text changes from 'click to turn on' to 'turning on'
3. and finaly after turning on, the list item enabled (with check box checked)

please help me...

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you know how to create a layout, bind it to an activity and get views with `findViewById`. If you don't just Google it

Achieving the effect you want it's pretty easy. That's how you do it:

- Use a switch in your layout ([see here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html)). It's the standard view for displaying an *on-off* button
- Set the switch text and the `onCheckedChangeListener`
- Update the switch status after job is done (following your example, activate bluetooth or wifi)

Here's a minimal working example:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   Switch testSwitch;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //get the switch from layout
    testSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.test_switch);

    //set text
    testSwitch.setText("Example switch");

    //set on checked change listener
    testSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {@
        Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
            //set switch text based on checked status
            if (isChecked) {
                compoundButton.setText("Turning on");
            } else {
                compoundButton.setText("Turning off");
            }

            //disable it
            compoundButton.setEnabled(false);

            //start the big long process (activate bluetooth or wifi). That's only an example
            afterSomeTime();
        }
    });
}
public void afterSomeTime() {
    //After 5 seconds update the switch
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            testSwitch.setEnabled(true);
            if (testSwitch.isChecked()) {
                testSwitch.setText("ON");
            } else {
                testSwitch.setText("OFF");
            }
        }
    }, 5000);
}
}
```

Hope this helps a little